# enable themes for applications

Tags: delphi

i have an old application (started in delphi 7 in Win XP), now i'm using delphi 2009 (win Vista). If i start a new project all buttons have a rouded edge, but in my old app all buttons have a "square"-shape look.

is there any setting that i've missed?
thanks

Comment: PS: i don't want to re-write my entire app to benefit of the new look of the buttons

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Under the Project Options in D2009, there is an "Enable runtime themes" option which is ticked by default for new projects but unticked for pre-existing projects.

Ticking this adds the manifest file to the EXE's resource, which is what makes it use Windows Xp/Vista themes, which is what gives you the rounded buttons.

http://www.stevetrefethen.com/blog/ThemingWindowsApplicationsInDelphi2007.aspx

http://www.stevetrefethen.com/blog/Delphi2007VCLDesignerThemeSupport.aspx

Comment: if possible, please remove the broken links

Answer (score 0):

You may have to create an application manifest file. The following links have some information:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/AddXpStyle.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997646.aspx