# App theme changes according to windows theme

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-2007

I am developing an application using Delphi 2007 (IDE CodeGear RAD Studio). This app is made to be used in Windows 7.

While developing an app I was using a Classic (Win98) theme, and my app has the same theme. Even beeing build on my computer and lunched on other computer with theme 'Aero', it looked as   'win98'.

After a while I changed my Windows theme to Aero, and my app started looking the same (Aero) way.

Later, when I swiched Windows theme back to Classic, my App started to look classic way.
But on computers with Aero App started to look like Aero.

So here is a question:

1. Is there any possible chance to prevent my app theme from changing (set theme to classic not depending on windows theme)?
2. Why did the theme start changing?

Comment: Because you've kept the `Enable runtime themes` check box in the project options checked (what is by default). See [`this article`](http://www.stevetrefethen.com/blog/Delphi2007VCLDesignerThemeSupport.aspx) or [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1613043/960757) for instance. If you uncheck this option, your application will look in the old style.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that while adding icon to my project I accidentally unchecked `Enable runtime themes` checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app includes the comctl32 v6 manifest, because the *Enable runtime themes* option is selected. Disable that option and your app will not be themed.